# Unable to print pass or fail message in output log using character map formatting

Tags: python

I need to print pass or fail message in output log. For example

```
FFFFFFFF   AAAAAAAA   IIIIIIII   LL       
FF         AA    AA      II      LL       
FF         AA    AA      II      LL       
FFFFFFFF   AAAAAAAA      II      LL       
FF         AA    AA      II      LL       
FF         AA    AA      II      LL       
FF         AA    AA   IIIIIIII   LLLLLLLL
```

Can anyone give me the logic or a existing python library to print the above.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic is:

```
def print_fail():
    print "FFFFFFFF   AAAAAAAA   IIIIIIII   LL"
    print "FF         AA    AA      II      LL"
    print "FF         AA    AA      II      LL"
    print "FFFFFFFF   AAAAAAAA      II      LL"
    print "FF         AA    AA      II      LL"
    print "FF         AA    AA      II      LL"
    print "FF         AA    AA   IIIIIIII   LLLLLLLL"

print_fail()
```